# Change HL7 outgoing value from HL7 incoming value using Javascript in Mirth Connect

Tags: javascript, hl7-v2, mirth-connect

Hi I'm trying to change the code and value in HL7 using Javascript in Mirth Connect. If the incoming msg has Code labeled `'B'` and `B = Boy` and I want to change the outgoing message to `'M'` and `M = Male`. How would I do that if the HL7 msg segment is in `msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1']`. I wrote down what I think the coding is below. Is it correct or am I missing something?

```
var PID8 = msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1']

var B = 'Boy'

var M = 'Male'

if (PID8 === B) {

msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1']().toString= 'M';

 } else if ('M');
```

Comment: What is the type of `msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1']` ? Also, your `else if` clause is useless, you can remove it.

Comment: The msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1'] is the location where the gender value is located in the HL7 messages.

Comment: Yes, is it a `String` or a `function` ? You can log it using `console.log` and `typeof msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if B for Boy
if (msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1'].toString() == 'B') {
    // change to M for Male
    msg['PID']['PID.8']['PID.8.1'] = 'M';
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL it's only two lines and both of them are commented with what they do?